# Java and Tomcat org.json java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, tomcat, servlets

I'm new to servlets, I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` whenever I try to include JSON library, I search the web and stackoverflow the only suggestion I found is to install dependencies I've Tried org.json , net.sf.json each with its dependencies nothing works and gives the same exception.

Any idea?

Comment: Which JSON library in particular are you trying to use? Where did you _include_ it?

Comment: I tried org.json then net.sf.json copied the libraries to WebContent\lib and included them in build path

Comment: Yes but which class is it that gives you a `ClassNotFoundException`? Is that class in those jars?

Comment: the `JSONObject` class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSONObject` is contained in `java-json.jar`. Make sure that have you have `java-json.jar` in your classpath. There are multiple places to put jars in tomcat depending which class loader you want the class to load.

If this jar is only required by your application then simply put it under your application directory in

`WEB-INF/lib`

It is worth reading how classes are loaded in Tomcat to place your jars optimally: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: thanks it works, but how and why do i need to change class loader?

Comment: @Warlock You don't have to change the class loader. But you should be aware how classes are loaded in Tomcat so that you can optimally places the jars. Read this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 4):

Try to put the libs for your web app in the directory

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
```

Comment: +1: And DON'T put it in the build path. Everything under WEB-INF/lib is automatically added to the build path by Eclipse.